# ELMA - передать значение переменной JS в контекстную

Tags: javascript, c#

В общем, вопрос в комментариях ...

```
  <script>
    function showHidText() {
        var vKontekst1 = $("#Entity_Stroka1");                  //Подключаемся к контекстно переменной Stroka1
        var vKontekst2 = $("#Entity_Stroka2");                  //Подключаемся к контекстно переменной Stroka2
        var hidStroki = vKontekst1.val() + vKontekst2.val();    //Проводим действия со значениями переменных

        a = document.getElementById('hid_text');                //Подключаемся к скрытому полю
        a.value = hidStroki;                                    //Присваиваем значение скрытому полю


        var vKontekst_h = $("#Entity_SkrytayaStroka");          //Подключаемся к контекстной переменной SkrytayaStroka
        vKontekst_h.value = a.value;                            //Присваиваем значение контекстной переменной SkrytayaStroka из скрытого поля 
        $("#Entity_Stroka1").value = vKontekst_h.value;         //Как отобразить присвоенное значение?

        alert("Значение скрытого поля: " + vKontekst_h.value);  //Сообщение показывает, что значение присвоено
     }
 </script>

<input type="button" onclick="showHidText()" value="Скрытое значение">

<input type="hidden" id="hid_text" value="123"/>
```

Comment: какая связь с `C#`?

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема у вас? Если я правильно понял вопрос, то ваш код работает как нужно

Comment: @Cheg, я тут вижу только одну проблему - использование свойства _value_ у объекта `jQuery`, если, конечно, под знаком `$` скрывается `jQuery`

Comment: Откуда такая странная терминология: _контекстная переменная_, _Подключаемся к контекстной переменной_, _Подключаемся к скрытому полю_?

Comment: Не работает здесь: $("#Entity_Stroka1").value = vKontekst_h.value; Значение не отображается в контекстной переменной Stroka1. Т.е. не могу обратно в контекст передать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы уж определитесь: использовать jquery или же нативный js.

```
function showHidText() {
    var vKontekst1 = $("#Entity_Stroka1");                  
    var vKontekst2 = $("#Entity_Stroka2");                  
    var hidStroki = vKontekst1.val() + vKontekst2.val();    

    var a = $('#hid_text');
    a.val(hidStroki);

    var vKontekst_h = $("#Entity_SkrytayaStroka");          
    vKontekst_h.val(a.val());                            
    $("#Entity_Stroka1").val(vKontekst_h.val());        

    alert("Значение скрытого поля: " + vKontekst_h.val());
 }
```

Comment: код написан в тестовом процессе Элма, как попытка передать значение из  js в контекст, которым является поле ввода "#Entity_" на форме. При Вашем варианте: vKontekst_h.val() - Undefined. Собственно, потому и такой расколбас в коде, что в одном случае работает js, в другом jquery. Передал вот так: $("#Entity_Stroka1").val("многобукв"); - сработало. Спасибо, теперь картина прояснилась )